# How to actually return the username instead of the id through manyToOne? (TYPEORM)

Tags: node.js, database, orm, typeorm

I have two entities, one of them is my User entity and a Post entity, inside my Post entity I get a ManyToOne referencing my user

post entity

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity('posts')
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    desc: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ 
        type: 'timestamp', 
        precision: 3
      })
      createdAt: Date;    
}
```

user entity

```
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column({
        default: ''
    })
    tokenResetPass: string;


    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    hashPassword() {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }

}
```

This is working, and every time I create a Post in user I send the Id of my user, but the issue is that when I get this my Post controller, I receive the user in Id format. How can I pull the "Username" inside the User entity in my get controller?

get controller post

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { AppDataSource } from "../../database/config";
import { Post } from "../../entities/Post";

class FindAllPostsController {
    async index(req: Request, res: Response) {

        try {
            const posts = await AppDataSource.manager.find(Post);

            return res.status(200).json(posts);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }
}

export default new FindAllPostsController();
```

Example of what I get in my postman:

```
{
    "id": "27febc4a-1461-4146-a839-bb860a947de2",
    "title": "test 1",
    "desc": "testing a post",
    "createdAt": "2022-12-17T16:52:39.196Z"
}
```

What I would like to receive:

```
{
    "id": "27febc4a-1461-4146-a839-bb860a947de2",
    "user": "username",
    "title": "test 1",
    "desc": "testing a post",
    "createdAt": "2022-12-17T16:52:39.196Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need load your relation. In your case:

```
const post = await AppDataSource.manager.find(Post, { relations: "user" })
```